# Chrome does not show Google webfonts - IE does. What´s wrong?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts, google-webfonts

I have a problem: I am using Google Webfonts for my new website. But when I open my website with Chrome, the fonts I have chosen are not shown. I can see the text but the font is not correct - its always the same lame font. 
The "funny" thing ist: This problem doesn´t occur with Internet Explorer. IE shows the fonts in the right way.

Can somebody please help me what´s wrong and tell me, how I can fix this.
That would be great.

Many thanks in advance.

Julia

Comment: Google Fonts should (and do) work in most browsers, including Chrome. Can you post details of how you're implementing them? [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/2bbYN/) works fine in Chrome (Canary/current)

Comment: Can you show us the code that you are using?

Comment: I implemented it with:
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> - and  body { font-family: 'Julius Sans One', sans-serif;}. Now I only take only a part of my code to show you, what I mean - and this little part is shown correct in Chrome. The whole code does only work with IE, not with Chrom.  I dont understand that.

Answer (score 0):

add to your CSS file

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gafata);
body {font-family: 'Gafata', sans-serif;};
```

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

Comment: Just a suggestion, try <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style>@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gafata);
body {font-family: 'Gafata', sans-serif;}</style>

Comment: Now I only took a part of my code to show you, what I mean - and this little part is shown correct in Chrome. The whole code does only work with IE, not with Chrom. I dont understand that.

Comment: The same problem with @import :-(

Comment: Could the chrome version be cached?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: I saved the .txt and the .html in the wrong encoding. It was "ANSI" and I have to choose "UTF-8". Now, everything works :-). Maybe I can help with this answer somebody, who makes the same mistake.

Thanks to all of you, who helped me.

Julia